# How to Filter a map of map based on another map using Lambda expressions

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a Map of Map  which needs to be filtered based of another Map  using lambda expressions

I tried to do filter on the map and find all matches based of another map but it doesnot seem to work. It seems the values are not filtered correctly.
Is there a way I can do streams and map and put the filtering logic there?
Can someone please help

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Map<String,List<String>> items = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> ut1=new ArrayList<>();
    ut1.add("S");
    ut1.add("C");
    List<String> ut2=new ArrayList<>();
    ut2.add("M");
    List<String> ut3=new ArrayList<>();
    ut3.add("M");
    ut3.add("C");
    items .put("1010016",ut1);
    items .put("1010019",ut2);
    items .put("1010012",ut3);
    System.out.println("Map"+items);

    Map<String,Map<String,String>> sKey = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String,String> utKey1 = new HashMap<>();
    utKey1.put("S","1001");
    utKey1.put("M","1002");
    utKey1.put("C","1003");

    Map<String,String> utKey2 = new HashMap<>();
    utKey2.put("S","1004");

    Map<String,String> utKey3 = new HashMap<>();
    utKey3.put("S","1005");
    utKey3.put("M","1006");

    Map<String,String> utKey4 = new HashMap<>();
    utKey4.put("S","1007");
    utKey4.put("M","1008");
    utKey4.put("C","1009");

    sKey.put("1010016",utKey1);
    sKey.put("1010019",utKey2);
    sKey.put("1010012",utKey3);
    sKey.put("1010011",utKey4);

    System.out.println("Map2"+sKey);

    Map<String,Map<String,String>> map3 =
        sKey.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(x -> 
                items.containsKey(x.getKey())
                && x.getValue().entrySet().stream().allMatch(y -> 
                    items.entrySet().stream().anyMatch(list ->
                        list.getValue().contains(y.getKey()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
    System.out.println("Map3"+map3);
 }
```

the filtered map is returning as:

> Map3{1010012={S=1005, M=1006}, 1010016={S=1001, C=1003, M=1002}, 1010019={S=1004}}

But the actual result should be:

> Map3{1010012={M=1006}, 1010016={S=1001, C=1003}}

Comment: From a glance, I don't see how you arrive at the expected result. I'm reformatting the code so I can read it at the moment though

Comment: Your Stream pipeline takes an input map, filters out some of its entries, and builds a map of all the entries that weren't filtered out. Therefore, you can't expect that the keys in the new map will have different values than the same keys in the input map.

Comment: is there a better way of doing this? instead of using allMatch and anyMatch?

Comment: Try re-reading the reformatted code, I think it shows the problems a little more clearly. You're going to need new lists, which I would do in your collector. Making use of Map#keySet and Set#retainAll will greatly shorten this code

Comment: is there a way I could do streams and map and write all the filtering logic there? I tried doing that but not been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will rather say this is a work around to achieve your expected output using stream.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = 
    sKey.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(detail -> items.keySet().contains(detail.getKey()) && 
            !Collections.disjoint(detail.getValue().keySet(), items.get(detail.getKey())))
    .collect(HashMap::new, 
            (m,v) -> m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(detail -> items.get(v.getKey()).contains(detail.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))), 
            HashMap::putAll);
```

**Output**

```
{1010012={M=1006}, 1010016={S=1001, C=1003}}
```